# What is turtle.colormode(255) for?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am a beginner to Python, and I have just started reading about turtle. I came across a bit of code （ forgot ） and I would like to know, what is the purpose of `turtle.colormode(255)`? Thanks!

Comment: see https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/8nkmcq/python_turtle_colormode/

Comment: The docs for this function are at https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/turtle.html#turtle.colormode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is the purpose of turtle.colormode(255)?

`turtle.colormode(cmode=None)` basically lets the programmer choose how they would like python to interpret the number passed into the brackets for the colors.

**There are these options for `cmode`: `1` and `255`.**

For the `1` mode, the programmer can only use numbers between `0` and `1` to represent the `rgb` scale, otherwise, a `TurtleGraphicsError` will be raised.

For the `255` option, the programmer can use numbers between `0` and `255`. When using the `1` option, the color

```
(0.33, 0.33, 0.33)
```

will be the equivalent of

```
(85, 85, 85) #(255*0.33, 255*0.33, 255*0.33)
```

when using the `255` mode.

---

For more information, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.colormode) for `turtle.colormode()`.

---